# line.replace is replacing with value even for a portion of key match instead of entire key match

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import subprocess

ip=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

reps= {'application.baseUrl': 'application.baseUrl="http://'+ip+':9000"',
'baseUrl': 'baseUrl="http://'+ip+':9000"'
}

f = open('/opt/presentation/conf/application.conf','r+')
lines = f.readlines()

f.seek(0)
f.truncate()

for line in lines:
        for key in reps.keys():

            if key in line:
                line = line.replace(line, reps[key])
        f.write(line+'\n')
f.close()
```

issue: it's replacing application.baseUrl with baseUrl="http://'+ip+':9000 instead of application.baseUrl="http://'+ip+':9000 since baseUrl is there in application.baseUrl.

how do i replace a key only if it matches entire string and not portion of string

file name : abc.config

application.baseUrl="http://ip:9000"

baseUrl="http://ip:9000"

remote {

```
log-received-messages = on

netty.tcp {

  hostname = "ip"

  port = 9999

  send-buffer-size = 512000b

  receive-buffer-size = 512000b

  maximum-frame-size = 512000b

  server-socket-worker-pool {

    pool-size-factor = 4.0

    pool-size-max = 64

  }

  client-socket-worker-pool {

    pool-size-factor = 4.0

    pool-size-max = 64

  }

}
```

}

Comment: Note that you don't have to do any tests at all (i.e. `'foo'.replace('Q','Z')` just returns `'foo'`, so you don't have to make sure the key is in the line before calling `str.replace`), but since one of your keys is a subset of the other, there's no GREAT way to do this without regular expressions.

Comment: What does `application.conf` look like? Could you also provide some expected input/output?

Comment: here the config file format:file name : abc.config

application.baseUrl="http://ip:9000"

baseUrl="http://ip:9000"

 remote {

    log-received-messages = on

    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "ip"
      port = 9999
      send-buffer-size = 512000b
      receive-buffer-size = 512000b
      maximum-frame-size = 512000b
      server-socket-worker-pool {
        pool-size-factor = 4.0
        pool-size-max = 64
      }
      client-socket-worker-pool {
        pool-size-factor = 4.0
        pool-size-max = 64
      }
    }
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want an exact matching instead of checking:

```
if key in line:
```

you should do:

```
if key == line[0:len(key)]:
```

or better yet, as Adam suggested in the comments below:

```
if line.startswith(key):
```

Comment: unless it doesn't start the line, and if it did you should use `if line.startswith(key)`. The only sure way to do it this way is `if any(key == line[start:start+len(key)] for start in range(0,len(line)-len(key)))`

Comment: Thanks Alfasin and Adam.

Comment: if key == line[0:len(key)]: it did work for above issue. but not if the file has : netty.tcp { hostname = "ip" port = 9999 pool-size=4.0} . it could not find "hostname" or "port" to replace key

Comment: @bvr if the file is in json format - better use a json parser (there's a json module in python).

Comment: @AdamSmith trying to handle all kinds of weird edge-cases seems an overkill in such a scenario. It will clutter the code and will be mostly unuseful, hit to performance and ugly to maintain.

Comment: @alfasin "edge case" like "search term doesn't start the line?" That's not exactly an edge case....

Comment: @bvr `key==line[0:len(key]` is exactly the same as `line.startswith(key)`. I have no idea why alfasin recommended that ugly construct. Regardless it means that it'll only trigger if your search term doesn't start the line. I voted down because there are no guarantees that that's the case. However I agree with alfasin that if you have JSON data, you should use a json parser.

Comment: @AdamSmith if you acknowledge a case where there are whitespaces in the beginning of the line then there could be whitespaces anywhere, you might want to handle an IP address that contains a space. Assuming the file was not generated manually - there shouldn't be any such "edge-cases" and if there are - it's another bug that should be fixed, not "patched" here with validations.

Comment: @alfasin I acknowledge the case where OP is searching for a term that doesn't begin the line. Whether the line begins with whitespace or not is irrelevant. Surely search and replace is still useful outside of the first set of characters in a line....

Comment: @AdamSmith Sorry if I sound harsh, it's just that I don't like doing any kind of parsing with regex. If a parser is required then the engineer should build one or use one that already exists. If the scenario is simple enough to substring - so be it, but if there are various kinds of scenarios then a parser should be used. As I mentioned before: I rather use regex only if it makes the code more readable (and thus easier to maintain), or if it makes the task much simpler. I don't feel that this is the case here.

Comment: Can't we do something in the same script to handle netty.tcp { hostname = "ip" port = 9999 pool-size=4.0} ? since other 2 parameters, I could replace with your solution.

Comment: the problem is some are in jason format and some are in each line by line in configuration file.

Answer (score -1):

You could use regular expressions instead:

```
re.sub(r"\b((?:application\.)?baseUrl)\b", r"\1=http://{}:9000".format(ip))
```

This will match `application.baseUrl`, replacing with `application.baseUrl=http://IP_ADDRESS_HERE:9000`, and `baseUrl`, replacing with `baseUrl=http://IP_ADDRESS_HERE:9000`

Regular expression explained:

```
re.compile(r"""
  \b                             # a word boundary
  (                              # begin capturing group 1
    (?:                            # begin non-capturing group
      application\.                  # application and a literal dot
    )?                             # end non-capturing group and allow 1 or 0 occurrences
    baseUrl                        # literal baseUrl
  )                              # end capturing group 1
  \b                             # a word boundary""", re.X)
```

and the replacement

```
re.compile(r"""
  \1                             # the contents of capturing group 1
  =http://                       # literal
  {}                             # these are just brackets for the string formatter
  :9000                          # literal""".format(ip), re.X)
# resulting in `r"\1=http://" + ip + ":9000"` precisely.
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using regex unless it makes the code much more readable or makes the task much simpler. This case is neither.

Comment: @alfasin I'd say that it makes the task REMARKABLY simpler, considering how much code you'll have to write for edge cases that get caught automagically by `\b`

Comment: Considering that I'm not handling *any* such edge-cases and not intending to write code for such, it is not simpler. Further, using regex (in any language) is unproportionally slower comparing to substring.

Comment: @alfasin I'd agree with you except that your solution works with op's test case and not their actual problem, as per op's comment on your answer. My solution is more robust than you imagine op would need, but your solution is too fragile for their use case. I'll go with the slightly slower solution that WORKS any day....

Comment: If the test case does not reflect the actual problem the question should be changed :)